# Why is my OpenOffice.org presentation opening in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, unicode

I have project created in OpenOffice.org Impress which is created in a local language. Today when I open it what I could see is:
[image: Screen shot]

When I open with the settings what I could see is Writer is opening which is complete of the symbol "#".
[image: Screenshot 2]

How can I recover my project?

Comment: Even I face this issue. So every time I want to work on a power point presentation I have to switch to windows. Hope the answer will help me as well.

Answer (score 3):

Libre Office shouldn't open an impress file in Writer, but in its own Impress. As such: Try to force it to open through Impress (via context menu or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> dialogue on Impress).

If that doesn't work, it's either an issue with the file extension or the collation you used, in which case we'd need more information on the file(s) in question.

Comment: Forcing open from Impress does not help. Saving to Microsoft Office format, upgrading LibreOffice and saving to .odp again worked.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your presentation is corrupted. If you still have a copy of the version of OpenOffice.org that you used, you can try to open it in there. If it opens fine, export it to ppt format (Microsoft Office 2003).

Do not try to save it from within Writer. If Impress will not open the file, then for sure your file has become corrupted.

To be sure, you can rename the file so that the file extension is .zip, and open it with Archive Manager. This will tell you if the file is corrupted (at the level of the compressed file) or if it is corruption in the xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start, make a copy of the 'corrupt' file for backup reasons.

> - Create an Impress demo-file, save and close it.
> - Go to the demo-file with the file explorer and do a right mouse click.
> - Open the demo-file with an archive manager or any other zip-manager.
> - Open the 'corrupt' file also with an archive manager.
> - Copy the file 'mimetype' from the demo-file-archive into the corrupt-file-archive that you're trying to repair.
> - Close the archives.
> - Do a double click on the corrupt-file, it will ask to repair the corrupt-file in a slightly other way.

Now your file should open in the impress application.